# How to get data at the beginning in Vue page

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

My problem is I want to get data at the beginning of the vue page. I tried to put those codes in mount() but it's still too late. After searching I think maybe created() is a good place or any places before generating the html code. But as I need to import a function so it seems that I cannot use created(). So I am wondering what's the better option to do that?

Right now my code looks like this

```
<template>
    {{ username }}
<template>
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
    name: 'page',
    data() {
        return {
            username = "whatever",
        }
    }
    mounted() {
        var firebaseConfig = {
        // some code
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        this.username = username from firebase
    },
}
</script>
```

But when I reload the page it shows whatever instead of the username I get from the firebase.

Comment: _"But as I need to import a function so it seems that I cannot use created()"_  what does this mean?

Comment: @Phil i tried to use firebase in this page. So I need to add import firebase from 'firebase'.

Comment: And why is that a problem?

Comment: @Phil when I put import inside created(), it shows me 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level. When I put import outside created(), which is at the beginning of script, I cannot use the api in firebase.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking without seeing any of this code you're trying. Could you please update your question?

Comment: @Phil just did that

Comment: You should initialise your Firebase app outside the `created()` hook but even with the code you've included, it's still very unclear what you're asking

Comment: @Phil sorry for unclear, just update it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firebase function needs to resolve before you set the username property. Async the mounted function & await the firebase call

Comment: thanks i just realized its a async function and that's the problem!

Answer (score -1):

The data initialization looks a bit odd to me.

[Usually data should be an Object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering)

In Your case i would suppose it to look something like this:

```js
data: {
    username: 'whatever'
}
```

And further on there seems to be a missing `,` between `data` and `mounted`.

[I created a fiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/82gz9kha/)

It is not a sfc but i think it is enough to make things clear.

Comment: thanks the answer! But I found my problem is as it's a async function so it seems that the variable get the data before it was assigned.